# Find the norm of a linear continuous operator

Tags: general-topology, analysis, normed-spaces

in $X=C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ with the norm $\|f\|_2=\sqrt{\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx}$

we define $T:X\rightarrow X$ by $Tf=gf$ for $g\in X$

How to prove that $T$ is continuous and how to find $\|T\|$ ?

I find the constant of continuity $\sqrt{\sup g^2}$ but i can't prove $\|T\|=\sqrt{\sup g^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f\in X$. For the sake of simplicity I'll write $\int f$ for $\int_0^1 f(t)dt$.

Let's use the scalar product on $X$ : $f\cdot g=\int fg$

$||Tf||^2=\int f^2 g2=f^2\cdot g^2$ so by the Cauchy Schwarz inequality, $||Tf||^4\le\int f^4\int g^4$.

We are searching for $||T||=\sup||Tf||,||f||=1$ so let $f'=\frac{f}{||f||}=\frac{f}{\int f^2}$.

Then $\forall f,||Tf'||^4\le\frac{\int f^4\int g^4}{(\int f^2)^4}$.

The equality in the Cauchy Schwarz inequality is obtained when $f^2,g^2$ are collinear thus $||T||=||Tg'||=\dfrac{\sqrt{\int g^4}}{\int g^2}$.

Comment: but why $f^2$ and $g^2$ are collinear ?

Comment: So that the equality is achieved, thus maximizing $||Tf||$.